# Trouble using file upload with Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, contact-form-7

I have set up *Contact Form 7* with file upload fields.

The form submits and sends emails okay as long as no files are included.

If the user selects a file via the file upload field, then the "processing" form goes on forever, and form is not submitted.

I notice that the file is uploaded to the "temporary" residence `wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_uploads/xxx`

However, it seems to me maybe the reason that the form doesn't submit might that CF7 is unable to then delete the file, which seems to have the permissions 0400. wpcf7_uploads and xxx both have 0755. How do I fix this?
Actually, I wouldn't mind storing the files on the server, and not remove them...that would be desirable...but either way, how do I get the form to submit with file upload?

Comment: have you referred the documentation https://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/

Comment: @omid-nikrah Of course! I have read the documentation, and it does not address the issue.